# Multiple histograms in highcharts causes an issue with bin spacing on the second histogram?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to plot two series of data and their corresponding histograms on the same chart.  Unfortunately the result is gaps between the bins of one of the histograms.

Has anyone any idea how to resolve this, bearing in mind that the data is dynamic so I don't want to explicitly set any bin widths etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/uwq9k7Lg/

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
            xAxis: [{
            }, {                
            }, {
            }],
            yAxis: [{
            }, {
            }],
            series: [{
                type: 'histogram',
                xAxis: 2,
                yAxis: 1,
                baseSeries: 's1'
            }, {
                type: 'histogram',
                xAxis: 2,
                yAxis: 1,
                baseSeries: 's2'
            }, {
                id: 's1',
                type: 'scatter',
                data: [1540.05,1532.99,1880.28,1477.81,1585.73,1517.52,1986.31,1469.12,1314.68,1769.32,1438.85,1559.51,1712.68,1539.97,1253.89,1830.8,1496.05,1490.26,1671.14,2442.06,1553.05,1493.59,1563.03,1486.62,1802.82,1373.39,1754.35,1525.61,1546.15,1505.9,1457.14,1800.56,1481.7,1349.72,2125.55,1621.02,1689.52,1685.67,1778.98,1698.82,1921.13,1520.81,1566.14,2372.76,1419.91,1796.7,1621.19,1816.31,1528.85,1342.83,2481.26,1694.68,1657.92,1457.89,1414.73,1857.76,1715.27,1530.2,1553.69,2890.06,1632.14,1419.08,1449.88,1414.45,1600.4,1473.22,1745.77,2536.96,1625.38,1788.98,1502.14,1414.55,1491.99,1389.6,1606.47,1865.12,2281.73,1466.92,1485.69,1492.09,2272.98,1656.43,1562.23,2229.11,1732.37,1466.74,1428.72,1209.87,1459.51,1618.47,1720.35,1660.64,1479.19,1425.42,1549.53,1645.3,1602.82,1608.41,1749.81,1714.55,1679.14,1791.71,1490.59,1928.39,1586.32,1494.97,1550.52,2608.26,1512.23,1804.93,1799.76,2493.59,2105.95,1765.73,1176.89,1789.19,1257.6,1701.47,1445.61,2308.24,1644.9,1590.58,2272.31,1449.72,1802.39,1385.58,1402.27,1562.01,1593.6,1585.58,1351.67,1563.42,1689.95,1332.75,2055.39,1567.86,1918.89,1669.67,1521.49,1936.59,1646.44,1735.57,1512.26,1727.84,1398.51,1437.52,1395.86,1704.65,1691.25,2436.58,1474.62,1971.48,1453.26,1274.71,1908.51]
            }, {
                id: 's2',
                xAxis: 1,
                type: 'scatter',
                data: [1796.39,1819.96,1644.75,1682.29,1664.81,2122.26,1442.42,1748.17,2099.26,1866.1,1466.9,2090.13,1502.34,1760.46,2279.47,1565.06,2104.19,1707.06,1827.82,1989.51,1899.41,1836.86,1633.83,2633.47,1860.75,2582.93,1500.57,2213.11,1417.45,1671.14,2305.97,3002.58,1802.91,1978.37,1914.84,1688.79,1967.32,1622.43,1705.98,1911.45,2040.99,2404.06,1788.33,1540.64,1900.35,1822.32,1995.54,2837.06,1840.97]
            }]
        });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `xAxis` and set `borderWith:0`

```
...
  xAxis: [{}, {}, {}, {}], // new xAxis
...
{
type: 'histogram',
   xAxis: 3, // Use the new added xAxis
   yAxis: 1,
   baseSeries: 's2',
   borderWidth: 0 // Remove the line around the bins
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fu1rj93g/)

Comment: I want their bins to be plotted on the same axis hough. To be able to compare one population to the other. Similar to what they have for men/women at http://marastats.com/halfmarathon/

Comment: Ok but you aren't comparing women and men but something like apples and fish. I don't see any other solution, sorry ...

Comment: I am actually, those two sets of data ARE men and women.

Comment: Sadly I think the conclusion I've come to is that the histogram type in highcharts isn't worth trying to use, and I'll just aggregate the data and do regular column charts instead.

Comment: Unfortuantely, I also don't see other solution for you. Actually, the effect which you need to achieve is not logical in my opinion, and it disturbs the whole concept of data presentation on the chart.